# How to import multiple folders into remix?

Tags: remix

I have about 50 contracts in 10 different folders. How do I bulk import/export them?

I already tried remixd, and that doesn't work.

I already tried remix desktop, but it doesn't have any explanation of how to interact with a wallet.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [an article](https://medium.com/authereum/debugging-solidity-with-a-gui-remix-and-ganache-c6c16488fcfd) about how to do this with `remixd`. The steps are as follows:

1. Install `remixd` on your local machine: `npm install -g @remix-project/remixd`
2. Run `remixd` on your local machine with `remixd -s <absolute-path> --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org`
3. Connect your project to remix.ethereum.org

Comment: the latest remixd version on npm doesnt work, but the one before that I was able to make it work. so I was able to do it

Comment: great article, thatnk you.

ps.
just update installation way to : `npm install -g @remix-project/remixd`

Comment: Thank you @skywinder! I have approved your edit.